# Why are the row spaces of equivalent matrices equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If you have matrixes $A$ and $B$, and $A \sim B $, $\text{row} (A) = \text{row} (B)$. I noticed this pattern in tons of matrixes and was wondering why it was true. Note the tilde sign means the matrices are equivalent by $B$ has had some elementary row operations performed on it.  (i.e. B is the row echelon form of A)

Comment: Perhaps it is true because no elementary row operation changes the row space?

Answer (score 1):

Each row in $B$ is a linear combination of the rows in $A$, hence $\operatorname{row}(B)\subseteq \operatorname{row}(A)$. Since the steps can be reverted, we also have $\operatorname{row}(B)\supseteq \operatorname{row}(A)$.

Comment: Could you explain why the rows in B being a linear combination of the rows in A imply the row space of A $\subseteq$ the row space of B?