# Why is $\text{Row}(A)=\text{Row}(\text{rref}(A))$ but $\text{Col}(A)\neq\text{Col}(\text{rref}(A))$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\text{Row}(A)$ denote the row space of a matrix $A$, and $\text{Col}(A)$ the column space.

Let $\text{rref}(A)$ denote the "reduced-row echelon form" of $A$.

Why is it the case that

$$\text{Row}(A)=\text{Row}(\text{rref}(A))$$

but

$$\text{Col}(A)\neq\text{Col}(\text{rref}(A))\,?$$

Comment: What do you mean =\?

Comment: I'm not sure what "rref" means (row-reduced echelon form, perhaps?) but the corresponding thing on the right hand side should probably by "cref" (column-reduced echelon form), which would then give you a true statement.

Comment: @HackerBoss: I think it's an attempt to write $\ne$. (OP: hint: to get that symbol in LaTeX, use `\ne`).

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking, but here is my guess. Do you want to know why the row rank of $A$ equals the row rank of the row-reduced echelon form of $A$, but the column rank of $A$ does not equal the column rank of the row-reduced echelon form of $A$?

Comment: rref is a reasonably standard abbreviation for reduced row-echelon form. Although I think it should be rcef on the right

Answer (score 1):

[Row operations preserve the row space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541718/why-are-the-row-spaces-of-equivalent-matrices-equal).

Therefore, if two matrices $A$ and $B$ are row-equivalent, their row spaces are equal. Since $\text{rref}(A)$ is row-equivalent to $A$, we have $\text{Row}(A)=\text{Row}(\text{rref}(A))$.

But [row operations do *not* preserve the column space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376284/do-row-operations-change-the-column-space-of-a-matrix).

For a counterexample, take $[1, 2]^T$. This column is row equivalent to $[1,0]^T$. But the column spaces of these matrices are not equal.

Thus, just because $A$ and $B$ are row-equivalent, it does not follow that $\text{Col}(A)=\text{Col}(B)$.

Comment: To expand on the first part, the point is that the row operations (exchange, multiply by non-zero scalar, and add multiple of one row to another) produce a new row which is easily seen to be in the span of the original rows. Thus the new row space is a subspace of the original. Since each of the row operations is reversible as a row operation, the same reasoning implies the old row space is a subspace of the new one. So the rows of both original and modified matrix span the same subspace.

Comment: @Ned: My answer doesn't need expansion. You're just literally repeating what the answer in the first link says.

Comment: Sorry I didn't click the link, I'm a little lazy, I guess.